# Set column width to content width in CSS Grid

Tags: css, css-grid

I hope every grid item should fit to its content width(400px), and keep the auto-fill. how can i do that?

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(240px, auto));
  grid-gap: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div style="background: aqua; height: 100px;">
    <div style="width: 400px; height: 100px;"></div>
  </div>
  <div style="background: aqua; height: 100px;">
    <div style="width: 400px; height: 100px;"></div>
  </div>
  <div style="background: aqua; height: 100px;">
    <div style="width: 400px; height: 100px;"></div>
  </div>
  <div style="background: aqua; height: 100px;">
    <div style="width: 400px; height: 100px;"></div>
  </div>
  <div style="background: aqua; height: 100px;">
    <div style="width: 400px; height: 100px;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply replace the `minmax(240px, auto)` with a fixed width of `400px`.

Note that this will create gaps when the width of the viewport isn't an exact multiple of 400, but elements will still be added to fill as much of the space as possible.

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 400px);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div style="background: aqua; height: 100px;">
    <div style="width: 400px; height: 100px;"></div>
  </div>
  <div style="background: aqua; height: 100px;">
    <div style="width: 400px; height: 100px;"></div>
  </div>
  <div style="background: aqua; height: 100px;">
    <div style="width: 400px; height: 100px;"></div>
  </div>
  <div style="background: aqua; height: 100px;">
    <div style="width: 400px; height: 100px;"></div>
  </div>
  <div style="background: aqua; height: 100px;">
    <div style="width: 400px; height: 100px;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: but the 400px may be change, I hope grid item should auto fit width with the inner div width( exemple: 400px)

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution. I just changed `grid-template-columns: 400px 400px;` property and fixed it to 400px.

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 400px 400px;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div style="background: aqua; height: 100px;">
    <div style="width: 400px; height: 100px;"></div>
  </div>
  <div style="background: aqua; height: 100px;">
    <div style="width: 400px; height: 100px;"></div>
  </div>
  <div style="background: aqua; height: 100px;">
    <div style="width: 400px; height: 100px;"></div>
  </div>
  <div style="background: aqua; height: 100px;">
    <div style="width: 400px; height: 100px;"></div>
  </div>
  <div style="background: aqua; height: 100px;">
    <div style="width: 400px; height: 100px;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

No Need to set Height It will be Set for the all div Automatically

```css
.grid--article {
        padding-bottom: 10px;
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 33.33% 33.33% 33.33%;
        grid-gap: 0.5rem;
    }
    .grid--wrapper {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 10px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="grid--article">
        <a class="grid--wrapper">your Text Goes here</a>
        <a class="grid--wrapper">your Text Goes here</a>
        <a class="grid--wrapper">your Text Goes here</a>
        <a class="grid--wrapper">your Text Goes here</a>
    </div>
```